# Completely center align Facebook like+share buttons?

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to align the Facebook buttons horizontally. Here's what I've tried:

```
//container with iframe or "fb-like" div
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.fb-like {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

- Leave out the width from the element (seems like it defaults to 300px)

Here is my problem: If I set the width too wide, it will not align center when the button text says "You like this". If the total width of both buttons and the text is 200 pixels, but the width is set to 300, it will be 100 pixels off (technically 50 to be aligned center).

If I instead simply set the width to 200 pixels, it will look fine when you like the page, but it will wrap the words if you don't like the page.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mo86wer2/

It will look aligned, but only if you don't like the page. How can this be achieved? I can't manipulate the content of the iframe, because it's an iframe.

Comment: add to container `.container {
      position:relative;
      left:50%;
    } ` and the buttons will be center of the page

Comment: @Eng_Farghly Uh no, that's not how it works.